# alternatives to infinite while loop in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, while-loop

Before calling `method2`, a NSTextField (`deviceDetails`) value must match a certain string pattern. As we can't know when the `NSTextField` takes the desired value, I implemanted an infinite while loop which checks the string pattern. Nonetheless, my CPU does not like this implemantation. Would you have some alternatives to this ?

```
[self method1]
NSString *recstate = @"string pattern.";

while (1) { 
    if ([[deviceDetails stringValue] isEqualToString:recstate])
    break;
          } 

[self method2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here.

> As we can't know when the NSTextField
>   takes the desired value

Of course you can know. You wouldn't be able to write very good apps if you couldn't. The Cocoa way to do this is to bind the NSTextField to a property in your model. When the value of NSTextField changes the value in your model changes. You can either write a custom accessor for your model property, or you can observe it using KVO.

Any good basic tutorial or book about Cocoa will cover this.